# Microtik L2TP Site-to-site

Tags: mikrotik

Задача объединить две сети в двух офисах. Оборудование - Микротики 3011.
Первый офис - локалка 192.168.32.0/24, сервер.
Второй офис - локалка 192.168.31.0/24, клиент.
Туннель 172.16.45.1 = 172.16.45.2 (роутинг) - поднялся.
Включен IPSec, туннель поднялся (состояние интерфейса - R), все вроде хорошо, но из туннеля в сеть ничего не ходит, сети друг друга не видят.
На фаерволах (обоих) проброс портов сделан (udp 500, 1701, 4500 и 50 протокол) с интерфейса ether1
Не пойму - чего не хватает, куда копать?

Comment: маршруты? разрешение в файерволе на входящие? пинг чезез тунель на 172.х.х.х и на 192.х.х.х?

Comment: Маршруты прописаны, из vinbox пингуются и роутеры по адресам 192.... и по 172 ....  НО: из роутера допустим 192.168.31.254 пингуется вся сетка другого офиса, но там всех адресов от 192.168.32.10 до 192.168.32.25, а пинги проходят на ВСЕ адреса этой сети!

Comment: dash1121
А из сети одного офиса (допустим 192.168.31.0.24) пингуется только сам роутер второго офиса (192.168.32.254) - остальная сеть - нет
Вроде как туннель работает (видит же 192.168.32.х) но из туннеля в сеть - ни пинга ни tcp. Все дропы фаервола выключаю - нифига.

Comment: В общем туннель работает, но в него ничего не попадает из LAN и из него ничего не идет обратно. На обоих роутерах. Что-то где-то надо прописать, но вроде все прописано, и роутинг и фаервол...

Comment: признаком рабочего тунеля будет рабочий пинг из одного роутера на адрес 172.ххх другого роутера. признаком рабочей маршрутизации пинг из одного роутера на адрес 192.ххх другого роутера. если пинг работает только в одну сторону, то стоит проверить не накручен ли нат.

Comment: Эти пинги идут в обоих направлениях. То есть 172.16.45.1 и 172.16.54.2 пингуются друг на друга, также и роутеры из винбокса 192.168.32.254 и 192.168.31.254 друг друга видят и пинги идут. НО! Из LAN 192.168.31.0/24 ответ пинга идет только от самого роутера второго офиса (192.168.32.254) - а от остальных устройств сети - нет, вот в чем загвоздка...

Comment: какой последний хост у tracert например от 192.168.31.11 к 192.168.32.11?

Comment: это роутер на той стороне (192.168.32.254) и на следующем прыжке он сообщает что заданный узел недоступен.

Comment: То есть видно всего два шага - первый местный роутер 192.168.31.254 и второй - роутер удаленный, 192.168.32.254. Дальше все, ничего нет, звездочки

Comment: на роутерах разрешен форвард между локалками по интерфейсу впн? если нет, то только роутер и будет отвечать.

Answer (score 0):

IP->Routs создать маршрут по типу 192.168.32.0/24 на втором офисе, аналогично и на первом!